# Write NSDictionary Array to SQLite3 Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

how can I write data from my NSDictionary * dictTemp to my SQLite3 database / update?
What is the best solution.
It's about updating a field (rating )

NSDictionary Demo Output :

```
2017-08-05 13:23:54.048340 TestApp [1904:979083] Club ID : 101  Value 3
2017-08-05 13:23:54.048498 TestApp [1904:979083] Club ID : 102  Value 1
2017-08-05 13:23:54.048579 TestApp [1904:979083] Club ID : 103  Value 5
```

SQLite3 Database :

[image]

Thanks for help

my code:

insert JSON to NSDictionary:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:getLiveRating];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LiveRatingDemo.json"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [manager GET:path parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id JSON)
     {
         NSDictionary *dictTemp = (NSDictionary *) JSON;
         NSArray *arrRating = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"ratingArray"];


         for (int i=0; i<arrRating.count; i++) {
             GetRating *rat = [[GetRating alloc] init];
             [rat parseResponse:[arrRating objectAtIndex:i]];
             [mratingLive addObject:rat];

         }
         NSLog(@"Success: %@", JSON);
```

save to database:

```
-(void)updateDatabase    
{


    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSString* db_ort = [DOCS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:DB_NAME];

    const char *dbpath = [db_ort UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO restaurants (rating) VALUES (\"%@\")", ratingValue];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            ratingValue = @"Rating Insert OK!";

        } else {
            ratingValue = @"Rating error ";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
```

What did I wrong this?

```
-(void)updateDatabase    
{
    NSLog(@"Datenbank wird Aktualisiert (get Rating JSON Data)");

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSString* db_ort = [DOCS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:DB_NAME];

    const char *dbpath = [db_ort UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
       // NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO restaurants (rating) VALUES (\"%@\")", ratingValue];

        for (int i=0; i<mratingLive.count; i++) {
            GetRating *rat = [mratingLive objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update restaurants Set rating = '%@' WHERE restaurantid = '%@'", rat.ratingValue, rat.ratingClubID];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            rat.ratingValue = @"Rating Insert OK!";

        } else {
            rat.ratingValue = @"Rating error ";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);


        }
    }
}
```

How can I relate the right strings , NSString... in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update a field in SQLite db, follow the below queirs

```
sqlite3 *database;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB_NAME.sqlite"];
sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;
if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update restaurants Set rating = ? WHERE restaurantid = '%@'", rat.ratingClubID] UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
     }

    if (sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [rat.ratingValue  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Error while binding value. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
     }

    if (sqlite3_step(updateStmt) != SQLITE_DONE){
        NSLog(@"Error  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Error while opening database");
}
```

Comment: can u help my please ? How can I install your code in mine?

Comment: Congratulations for re-inventing "SQL injection".

Comment: @user3182142 thank is perfect for my !!! Other problem, how can I empty the NSDictionary before the new download starts, cache old data :-(

Comment: remove the cache

Comment: You are not closing the curly bracket in many of if the statements.  It seems to me that you are finalizing the statement without updating anything.

Comment: Downvoted because of SQL injection, which is created by using ordinary string functions to build queries. The biggest source of easy hacker attacks against SQL databases. You don't know what's inside rat.ratingClubID. By putting the right string into that variable, I can easily destroy your database.

Comment: By the time you call sqlite3_bind_text, the damage is long done. stringWithFormat already replaces %@ with the rat.ratingClubID. The string sql doesn't contain any %@ anymore.